# How can I represent exogenous I(0) variable in VECM / Cointegrating relationship?

Tags: stationarity, cointegration, trend, vector-error-correction-model

So I am doing an econometric study on Bitcoin's USD price. As an exogenous regressor, I have the total number of bitcoins in circulation (**nbtc**). The graph looks like this:
[image: Graph of number of bitcoins over time]

This variable is:

1. Exogenous – It can affect my other variables in the model, but they cannot affect it; the number of bitcoins increases as a diminishing rate (halves every 2 years) to a maximum of ~21m.
2. I(0) – if I include a trend and controlling for the structural break, this is basically just a straight line.

So what we have here is linear trend. Now, this ***should*** be in my model and ***should*** (theoretically) affect the USD price in the **long-run**, but it can't form part of the **long-term** cointegrating relationship between my variables (Johansen tests find one such linear relationship), because it is I(0) and cannot "correct" any disequilibrium itself.

How would this be addressed in a VECM model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general points:

1. The variable in the picture does not seem to have a linear trend, but perhaps its logarithm would. In any case, there seems to be a structural break somewhere at the end of 2012.
2. If there are convincing subject-matter reasons why the variable should not cointegrate with other variables, you do not need to test for cointegration; if you are in doubt, you can of course do that.
3. Note that trending variables may be mistaken for integrated variables (and vice versa) and care needs to be taken to account for deterministic trends in test specifications (this holds both for unit root tests and the Johansen cointegration test).
4. Stationary exogenous regressors can be included in a VECM; they need not be used at the stage of cointegration testing, but they may be included at the stage of assembling the model. In your case you would need to stationarize the variable in the picture; you could detrend it and also account for the structural break. The problem appears to be, how to account for the long-run effect of the variable. Perhaps you could try including lags of the variable. If the lag order is quite high, you might want to use regularization (shrinkage) to prevent overfitting.

Comment: Do you have any examples of where regularization as you suggest here has been successfully applied? When attending a talk at a conference in December I got the impression that it has not been well studied in VECM in general, but if you have examples I'd gladly read them.

Comment: There is [some work](http://cmstatistics.org/RegistrationsV2/CFE2015/viewSubmission.php?id=817&token=q43r21rrpo415o0818s61np8827qn11n) by Kascha & Trenkler presented at the conference of Computational and Financial Econometrics in London, 2015 (is there any chance that we attended the same conference **?**). I don't know if they have published anything yet, though. I have a paper under review where I find VECM with regularization to perform relatively well (actually, best among a bunch of models considered -- but these other models may or may not be very competitive).

Comment: Yes, that's the one! That is funny that we were both in the same session. There was also something in another session chaired by Smeekes. I am thinking about this presentation: CO1534: A comparative study on forecasting performance of high-dimensional time series methods. Is there a working paper or published draft of your submission?

Comment: @hejseb, I have not published the draft. It will take a while to get that publication out since it is just the first round of the review process. Anyway, it was my first attempt at applying regularization in a time series setting, so I do not consider it advanced or anything. It just happened to work OK, but even though it was competitive amongst the candidate models, its performance was not significantly superior (no wonder as I was forecasting a financial time series which is not much different from a random walk).

Comment: 1) once you account for the break, doesn't it effectively become linear?
2) Hmm. Eventually it will become a horizontal line, and is totally exogenous to the model. The problem is that it is exogenous – no other variable an affect it, but it can affect the variables. Does this mean it can be cointegrated?

Comment: 1) Perhaps. 2) In principle, cointegration can have unidirectional feedback such that variable $x_2$ adjusts towards variable $x_1$ but not vice versa, and so $x_1$ is said to lead $x_2$. However, for cointegration first you need variables driven by stochastic trends, a property which the variable in the picture might not posess.

Comment: My variable is not driven by a stochastic trend. It does not fluctuate at all. It increases at a known rate, but could certainly affect my variable of interest. I guess another way of putting it is that the Data Generating Process is known in advance, including the structural break. This is not one realisation of a process, it will always produce this line. How do I include this in my model?

Comment: OK, then it must be a deterministic trend. If you can perfectly predict it in advance rather than estimate from the data, then you could just include it with a fixed (restricted to one) coefficient value. If you estimate it from the data but you know it is linear, or piecewise linear, use some trend and dummy variables to account for it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but why would I restrict the coefficient to one?

Comment: Excuse my hastiness... On a second thought, often you wouldn't. I thought of it as a known effect rather than known-shape, unknown-size effect. But there may sometimes exist factors the effect of which is completely known, so you would effectively just subtract that effect, that is why I thought of fixing the coefficient to one.

Comment: Yes, it's a known-shape, unknown-size effect. In this case, shall I include it as an exogenous regressor (and accounting for the structural break), even though it affects my variable of interest in the long-run?

Comment: Sounds fine, just pay attention to point 5. in my answer. You will need to first-difference this variable to match the fact that the dependent variable on the left hand side is a first difference.

Comment: @hejseb, I found an example where Francis X. Diebold uses (apparently successfully) elastic net regularization on VAR models: ["Financial and Macroeconomic Connectedness" website](http://financialconnectedness.org/info_stock.html). That is not VECM, but does that really matter? After all, VECM is but a VAR in first differences plus the error correction terms on the right hand side.

Comment: @hejseb, there is some work on regularization and multivariate time series (including cointegrated ones) by Cristophe Croux, Ines Wilms, Luca Barbaglia and coauthors (all at KU Leuven). They might be the first ones who published serious results on LASSO for VAR etc.